# Run command in cmd.exe

Tags: cmd, command, yii2

I am looking to run a command in the cmd.exe from the yii2 application. I am on localhost and have admin rights.

The file I am trying to run the command from has the following path:
`C:\Server\htdocs\hr\commands\EmployeecronController.php`

The code looks like this:

```
class EmployeecronController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
       [Code]   
    }
}
```

This is what I enter into the console:

[image: cmd Error message]

Comment: in actionIndex() use `if (STDIN) {
            echo "you are running on cmd";
        } else {
            return 0;
        }`  and run like this `php index.php`

Comment: run following command `yii employeecron` or `php yii employeecron` or `yii  employeecron/index`

Comment: Try it with a forward slash `/` and not the backslash.

Comment: Ok that was the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Make sure you placed controller in right folder:

- for basic application - `commands` folder;
- for advanced application - `console/controllers` folder.

**2)** Make sure correct namespace is specified:

- for basic application - `namespace app\commands;`;
- for advanced application - `namespace console/controllers`;

**3)** You need to call it like that:

```
php yii employeecron/index
```

or

```
yii employeecron/index
```

You can omit index because it's default action:

```
php yii employeecron
```

For complex controller and action names, for example `LongContollerName` you need to separate it with dashes (as with regular web controllers):

```
php yii long-controller-name/long-action-name
```

Comment: I assume your solution works normally, I couldn't replicate because I think my problem lies elsewhere (see my reply).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for me the problem was the following, I had to enter it like this:
`C:\Server\htdocs\hr> C:/Server/php/php.exe yii employeecron`